# mapbox gl- Toggle highlighting of specific feature of a layer in map style

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I tried it with "Setpaintproperty" and "data driven functions" but I dont know the exact syntax..

```
    map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var states = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
     layers: ['n_Region6 Municipals']
    });
  map.setPaintProperty('n_Region6 Municipals', 'fill-color',' 
  {"property":"NAME_2","type":"category","stops": + 
  [[states[0].properties.NAME_2 +,"blue"]]}');// im not sureif this is 
                                                 allowed
```

I see some Instructions on the web using filter but it makes you add 2 or more layers and I dont want that.I only what to use the existing layer in the map style.is that posssible in Mapbox GL?how to code it simply?

Comment: I think maybe you have a typo, the type value should be "categorical" not "category" https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#function-type

Though I believe using a second layer with a filter is simpler that using data driven styles, that is how I do it in my apps.